# Kali NetHunter KeX error ESM mode

Tags: linux, kali-linux, vnc, tightvnc

When entering the KeX application, an error is thrown
"Connection to VNC failed"
When I enter the terminal and try to run through kex, I get:

*/usr/bin/kex: line 291: cmdkey.exe: command not found
Please enter ESM password for user root:
/usr/bin/kex: line 371: mstsc.exe: command not found*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try running Kali in a Virtual Machine.   Kex refers to WSL

Comment: so my kali is on android